# Add comment for objective-c like what we do with java-doc

Tags: objective-c, javadoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaDoc-like documentation for Objective-C in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225816/javadoc-like-documentation-for-objective-c-in-xcode)
>   [How to decorate Objective C methods with documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417435/how-to-decorate-objective-c-methods-with-documentation)

I am new with objective-c. I want to add some comments for my methods so I can see these comments anywhere, anywhen I type the name of these methods and press Ctrl - Space bar. This is similar what we do with java or C#. Please give me some steps to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) (see this answer: [Xcode: show documentation for my custom classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958413/xcode-show-documentation-for-my-custom-classes))